# passing information from a Drupal Forms API validation function to a submit function

Tags: drupal, drupal-fapi

In my validation function for a Drupal Forms API form, I attempt to charge the user's credit card. If it succeeds, I'd like to pass the reference number to the submit function so it can be used there.  What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Hrrm. I realized that I didn't actually answer the question you asked at all. It should apply to the problem a little more now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/file/developer/topics/forms_api_reference.html/6#val) says this:

> Note that as of Drupal 6, you can also simply store arbitrary variables in $form['#foo'] instead, as long as '#foo' does not conflict with any other internal property of the Form API.

So you could do something like this:

```
function form($form_state) {
//in your form definition function:
$form['#reference_number'] = 0;
}

function form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  //try to charge card ...
  if ($card_charged) {
    $form_state['values']['#reference_number'] = $reference_number;
  }
}

function submit_form($form, &$form_state) {
  if (isset($form_state['values']['#reference_number'])) {
    $reference_number = $form_state['values']['#reference_number'];
    //do whatever you want
  }
}
```

Comment: The $form_state variable is definitely where you want to stick that information -- it's exactly what it's intended for, and (amusingly enough) 'credit card verification during validation' was one of the example use cases used to justify the design of the current validation/submission workflow.